# Remove first 5 lines from every PDF page in Python

Tags: python, nlp, text-extraction

I need to extract text from a pdf using Python (NLP application), and want to leave out the first 5 lines from the text on every page. I tried looking online, but couldn't find anything substantial. I am using the below code to read all text on the pages. Is there a post-extraction step that can remove from all pages the first few lines, or maybe something that can be done at extraction stage itself?

```
fileReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file)
s=""
for i in range(2, fileReader.numPages):
    s+=fileReader.getPage(i).extractText()
```

Answer (score 1):

split text with "\n" and slice to remove the first 5 lines:

```
import pdfplumber

pdf = pdfplumber.open("CS.pdf")
for page in pdf.pages:
  text = page.extract_text()
  for line in text.split("\n")[5:]: 
    print(line)
```